# Child items are not inheriting the metadata from Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set, classic-experience

I have a classic document library with around 8K items in it. For a few of the document sets, the child items are not inheriting the metadata of the parent even though all the columns are shared columns.

This is an intermittent issue as for other document sets the behavior is as expected.

Things already checked:

1. Verified the document set settings and it is correct.
2. Created a new document library and behavior is as expected.

Can it be the issue because of 8K items on the list?

Please let me know if anything else I can check here as it is a blocker in Production.

Comment: Have you contacted MSFT support? I'm not aware of a software boundary regarding document sets and the 5k list view threshold.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to raise support ticket